# Don't store the encfs password, require explicit mounting

Tags: mount, password, encfs

I use encfs to encrypt some data in my dropbox directory. Everything works well. For simplicity let's assume that i have created the directories `~/encrypted` and `~/decrypted`. Every time I log in into my linux account `~/decrypted` will automatically be mounted. Is there a way to avoid this and force the user (me in my case) to enter the password before `~/decrypted` can be mounted?

I use Linux Mint 17.3 with Cinnamon. I imagined that my encrypted folder is unmounted all the time except when want to access it. Then a little dialog could appear where I have to enter my password.

Comment: What distribution are you using, what version, and what desktop environment?

Comment: Sorry for not answering. I use Linux mint 17.3 with cinnamon. I imagined that my encrypted folder is unmounted all the time except when want to access it. Then a little dialog could appear where i habe to enter my password

Comment: How do you even "automatically mount" an encfs directory? That's not a part of standard functionality. Are you sure you are even talking about `encfs` specifically here? Maybe you are using some other tool?